# VS-code says: Unknown css property for 'accent-color'

Tags: css, vue.js, visual-studio-code, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt project. In one of my SFC, I am trying to use the 'accent-color' css property.

But, **Vscode gives the warning:** **Unknown css property 'accent-color'** and the code fails to compile. Can anyone please tell me how to fix this?

Here's the code:

```
<style scoped>
.styled {
  height: 1rem;
  width: 1rem;
  accent-color:red
}
</style>
```

Comment: What are your targetted browsers? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/accent-color#browser_compatibility

Comment: I am using Chrome. Current version is: 93.0.4577.82

Comment: @Danny1911 He's asking you what browsers your app is being built for (this is usually indicated in the `.browserslistrc` file or `browserslist` property in `package.json`).

Comment: That warning should not fail your build though, unless you have an aggressive style linter. What utility is failing your build? Configure it to ignore that warning.

Comment: Ohh sorry for that @kissu and @tony19. I dont have the `.browserlistrc` nor the `browserslist` property in package.json. But I get what you are saying @tony19 . I ll try to configure my eslint and prettier. Thanks guys !

P.S. The code is compiling successfully. I was making a mistake. My bad!